# Project Euler #79: Using the Python standard library only, can a function be defined to sort the Passcode digits order from the given set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem in matter can be found here: [Problem #79](https://projecteuler.net/problem=79)

"A common security method used for online banking is to ask the user for three random characters from a passcode. For example, if the passcode was 531278, they may ask for the 2nd, 3rd, and 5th characters; the expected reply would be: 317.

The text file, keylog.txt, contains fifty successful login attempts.

Given that the three characters are always asked for in order, analyse the file so as to determine the shortest possible secret passcode of unknown length."

So far I've been able to find the number of digits making up the passcode, but I can't order them.
I'm working on defining a simple function that will return the position of each digit in regard with the others and finally figure out the final position and the Passcode.

If anyone can help, here is my work so far:

```
# Open the file and create a list from a set in order to remove duplicates.
with open('D:\\Development\\keylog.txt', 'r') as file:
    logins = list(set(file.read().split()))

# Create three separate sets with the positions of the digits.
first_digits = set()
second_digits = set()
third_digits = set()

for login in logins:
    first_digits.add(login[0])
    second_digits.add(login[1])
    third_digits.add(login[2])

newSet = (first_digits | second_digits | third_digits)

# After the three sets are combined it will return another set of 8 digits.
# From this we can deduce that the shortest passcode is made from the 8 different digits.
# The set looks like this: {'3', '7', '2', '6', '1', '0', '9', '8'}

# def A function that gives the order of the digits in the passcode.
```

I've tried a few variations of functions like "is_before(x)" or "is_after(x)" but it gets way to complicated for me and also not working or returning the final answer.

Comment: Couldnt you just take the first Element of the List, define it as the string to be worked on, and then if an element of the list has the same first two as the strings last two chars, the last char of the element of the list is added to the end of the string, and then ofcourse the check for the other way around. You pop everything from the list that is already used or even already fully in that string, and as the list is empty, you just return the final result.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and correct output so that you can test if a solution is correct?

Comment: @CryptoFool input is in the question they linked https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p079_keylog.txt and correct output is unknown to them. ProjectEuler is the website where you can do this kind of questions to practice programming and logical thinking. Usually some math problems that require programming to be solved because it would take hours to solve them manually.

Comment: @CryptoFool Yes. I'm at the point where I've identified the digits of the passcode (newSet) and the number of digits that will make the passcode (8). The output should be something like this: '7' is before all the other digits from the set thus 7 is the first in the passcode, or '9' is after all the other digits in the set thus 9 is the last digit in the passcode. Finally reasoning out for the entire passcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and checked it with Project Euler as it is correct.
Thanks to those who tried to help and here is my version.

```
with open('D:\\Development\\keylog.txt', 'r') as file:
logins = list(set(file.read().split()))

first_digits = set()
second_digits = set()
third_digits = set()
for login in logins:
    first_digits.add(login[0])
    second_digits.add(login[1])
    third_digits.add(login[2])
newSet = (first_digits | second_digits | third_digits)


def digits_before(x, attempts):
    before_digit_x = set()
    for attempt in attempts:
        if x in attempt:
            for digit in attempt:
                if digit == x:
                    break
                else:
                    before_digit_x.add(digit)
    return before_digit_x


def get_passcode(digits, attempts):
    passcode1 = []
    for digit in digits:
        before_digit = digits_before(digit, attempts)
        if not before_digit:
            passcode1.append(digit)
        else:
            for d in passcode1:
                if d in before_digit:
                    passcode1.insert(passcode1.index(d), digit)
                    break
            else:
                passcode1.append(digit)
    return "".join(reversed(passcode1))

passcode = get_passcode(newSet, logins)
print(passcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you believe that the answer is ten digits or less with no digit repeated?  (A much harder problem would have strings like both 762 and 726, and you would have to figure out which gives you the shorter solution.)

In that case just repeat the following:

1. Find a digit that only appears as the first digit of your remaining strings.
2. Add that digit to the key code
3. Remove that digit from front of every string that it appears in.  If the string is now empty, remove it.
4. If you've removed all the strings, you're done.  Otherwise, go back to step 1.

In essence, this is a simplified topological sort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

The assumption here is that the digits appear only once in the passcode. That's based on the "keylog.txt" that does not have any duplicate digits in the given login attempts.

There are no login attempts like xxy or yxy or any other combination. All of them are in the form xyz.

If my reasoning is correct by this point I've figure out that 8 digits is shortest possible passcode with the given input(keylog.txt) It could be shorter or longer depending on the input.

Comment: I should also add that the algorithm above will fail if the password needs a repeated digit.  At some point, you will have strings remaining, but there won't be any digit that only appears at the front.   It certainly looked like this would work for the example you were given.